# How to select DataGridViewRow by code

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to select entire row if cell in column 0 contains specified value. I have a TextBox and DaraGridView. Under one scenario, value from selected row is copied to the TextBox on DoubleClick event of DGV. But on TextChanged event of the TextBox I want to check first column of DataGridView and if value is found, select that row (cell), then copy value from selected row's cell 2 to TextBox.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **TextChanged** event of your textbox. you can try this code.

```
DataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().
Where(x => (string)x.Cells[0].Value == txt1.text).
ToArray<DataGridViewRow>()[0].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Leave event of TextBox1, do this:

```
                    try
                    {

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (r != null)
                        {
                            if (String.Compare(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), TextBox1.Text) == 0)
                            {
                                r.Selected = true;
                                TextBox1.Text = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
```